# How to properly say that somebody will gift an item to the winner of a quiz?

Tags: sentence-choice

Let's say I have a quiz: a winner (who will answer the question first) will get a smartphone.
Should I say "we'll give away a smartphone" if it's part of a quiz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're *giving away* a smartphone. For added clarity, you could say you're giving away a smartphone *as a prize* to the winner.